# Laravel uploading file using vue3

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-8, vuejs3

i am trying to upload file in Laravel storage folder using vue3 composition API. i have added code but file is not being uploaded.

routes are correct, only **`null`** value is being added in mysql.

i have 3 columns in mysql database.

`id` | `file_name` | `file_path`

**html**

```
 <input    ref="file" v-on:change="handleFileUpload()"  type="file" />

 <button @click="senddata" class="">UPLOAD</button>
```

**Vue function:**

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
import { defineComponent,ref } from 'vue'
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {

      const file = ref(null)
     const handleFileUpload = async() => {
           // debugger;
            console.log("selected file",file.value.files)
            //Upload to server
        }


function senddata() {
    
     axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/store-files',{
     file:this.file,
     
      }).then(response=>{
      message=response.data.message; 
      alert(message);

      });
}

    return {
        senddata,
        handleFileUpload,
        file
    };
}
})
</script>
```

**Laravel Store Controller:**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
 $file=new Files();
  if($request->file()) {
            $file=new Files();
             $file_name = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
             $file_path = $request->file('file_link')->storeAs('uploads', $file_name, 'public');
 
             $file->file_name = time().'_'.$request->file->getClientOriginalName();
             $file->file_path = '/storage/' . $file_path;
             $file->save();
             return response()->json([
                'message' => 'File  added'
            ]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you cannot send file in json, you need to send via `FormData`

you need to write code like

#### html

```html
 <input    ref="file" v-on:change="handleFileUpload"  type="file" />

 <button @click="senddata" class="">UPLOAD</button>
```

#### Vue function

```js
handleFileUpload() {
   const file = ref(null)
   this.file = file.value.files;
}


function senddata() {
    
   let formData = new FormData();
   formData.append('file',file)

     axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/store-files',formData).then(response=>{
      message=response.data.message; 
      alert(message);

      });
}
```

ref link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Thankoyu, i need to add <form> in html as well?, i hope nothing is wrong with laravel controller.

Comment: no need only `new FromData` in javascript

Comment: error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target')

Comment: `v-on:change="handleFileUpload" ` here i remove `()` please check that

Comment: under vue code, error is showing with handleFileUpload(e) { ,"expected semi colon after (e)" if i add semi colon after (e); it says e is not defined.

Comment: try this then `this.$refs.file[0]` in vue2 that code was working

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: it is not present in vue 3 i guess